# Where exactly is AWS Websocket API running and how can it utilize lambda functions?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, chalice

Reading https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api.html I am confused. Where exactly the WSS is being hosted and where is the processing happening?

> In API Gateway you can create a WebSocket API as a stateful frontend
> for an AWS service (such as Lambda or DynamoDB) or for an HTTP
> endpoint. The WebSocket API invokes your backend based on the content
> of the messages it receives from client apps.

So if I use Chalice to deploy my API with websocket support, is it automatically running processing on Lambda? Or do I have to write that manually in boto (ex. `invokeFunction`) or can I point it to a lambda function?

The maximum lambda function runtime is 15 minutes.

The maximum websocket timeout is 2 hours and 10 minutes of idle.

For example, what happens to the `run_some_long_function()` that exceeds 15 minutes? If the Lambda function exceeds 15 minutes, does this just disconnect?

```
from boto3.session import Session
from chalice import Chalice

app = Chalice(app_name='ws-service')
app.experimental_feature_flags.update(['WEBSOCKETS'])
app.websocket_api.session = Session()

app.debug = True


@app.on_ws_connect()
def ws_connect(event):
    app.log.debug(f"New connection established: {event.connection_id}")
    response = run_some_long_process()
    app.websocket_api.send(event.connection_id, response)
```

I'm also confused as to where the function runs, does it run on Lambda?

Going deeper, looking at the code here on the [chalice tutorial](https://aws.github.io/chalice/tutorials/wschat.html), where are the websocket connections being hosted on? Is `wss://{id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/api/` running on lambda?

Comment: lambda is ephemeral, not expected to run for a long time, so the timeout isn't really an issue here, it should respond quickly to events.  In the case of wss, those events include a connectionId that you can use to track the state of each connection (in a database like Dynamo, for example).  The API Gateway keeps the connection alive.  If you need to run some very long process in response to a wss request, you won't be able to do it in Lambda.

Comment: thanks @AnonCoward, what is the normal procedure to handle such long processes on AWS if its too long for Lambda? Spin up a Lightsail server or ec2? I guess startup time is less important here since the user expects to wait a while until it returns something.

Comment: Too many possible variables to suggest the "normal procedure".  Using an ASG with EC2 is one option, ECS is another.  Depends on what exactly is being done.